# Relation between QCI and Bearer in LTE

Tags: lte, 4g

I was reading through LTE specifications in order to understand the number of bearers that could be created per UE.

[Spec 23.203](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/123200_123299/123203/12.06.00_60/ts_123203v120600p.pdf) - Table 6.1.7: Standardized QCI characteristics, defines 9 values for QoS(Quality of Service) based on performance characteristics of IP packets while according to [Spec 24.007](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/124000_124099/124007/10.00.00_60/ts_124007v100000p.pdf) - Table 11.5: EPS bearer identity, E-RAB IDs 5-15(11 bearer IDs) are usable.

I am unable to comprehend whether the number of bearers can be 9 or 11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for 2 EPS bearers to have to the same QCI. For example, they could be flowing to different PGWs, but have the same QCI. Hence based on the number of identifiers available, the answer is 11.

Comment: Yes, if there are different PGWs QCI could be same but can it be same for two bearers on the same PGW? Could there be any such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

QCI 1 to 9 are pre-defined settings and given by 3GPP for every operator and network vendors. This allows for interoperability among vendors.

However, operators can create their own QCI from 10 to 255 with their own customized settings for a particular service (like maximum allowed delay, priority, GBR or Non-GBR, etc.

It's worth noting that is very unlikely that a mobile will use that number of bearers at the same time. Typically you have just one (QCI 9) for pretty much everything you do (including Skype, WhatsApp call or streaming).

If on the top of that you also have voice over LTE, then you get QCI 1 while you're in a call and QCI 5 for IMS signaling.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

LTE QOS de nes priorities for certain customers or services during congestion. In LTE Broadband Network QoS is implemented between CPE and PDN Gateway and is applied to a set of bearers. 'Bearer' is basically a virtual concept and is a set of network con guration to provide special treatment to set of tra c e.g. VoIP packets are prioritized by network compared to web browser tra c. In LTE, QoS is applied on Radio bearer, S1 bearer and S5/S8 bearer, collectively called as EPS bearer as shown in gure below
for more [enter link description here](http://telecom-hyb.blogspot.com/2018/08/QCI-in-LTE.html)